# How to add background image in inline CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a background image in WordPress ( inline css) but I can't figure out how to do it as WordPress supports only inline CSS.

Can anybody help me how to do that?

Comment: How you are adding BG Image? Also who told that `WordPress supports only inline CSS`?

Comment: You can edit style.css under theme editor. no need to go for inline.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="background: transparent url(put your image url here) center top no-repeat; margin: 20px auto; padding: 45px 10px 20px; width: 90%; ">
YOUR POST TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the automated warning and check the preview window. Code must be indented to be shown properly.

Comment: Explain your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10634193)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add background image its not compulsory to use inline css.You can add css into the theme css ie in style.css